# Find the horizontal asymptote(s) of the function

Tags: limits, functions

I need to find the horizontal asymptote(s) of the following function:

$$f(x) = \frac{-2e^x + x^2}{3e^x + 5}$$

This needs to be done using limits, and I know I need to apply the limit as x approaches infinity. However, I can't seem to get the right answer, which is -2/3.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{-2e^x+x^2}{3e^x+5} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{-2+x^2e^{-x}}{3+5e^{-x}} = \dfrac{-2+\lim_{x \to \infty}x^2e^{-x}}{3+\lim_{x \to \infty}5e^{-x}} = -\dfrac23$$

Comment: Exponents trump polynomial growth! $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-2e^x+x^2}{3e^x+5}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-2e^x}{3e^x}=-\frac23$

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

Since $$f(x)=\frac{-2e^x+x^2}{3e^x+5}=\frac{-2+x^2e^{-x}}{3+5e^{-x}}$$ you need take limit when $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Since $e^x\ne 0$ divide each term in the function by $e^x$ and note that $\dfrac{x^2}{e^x}$ and $\dfrac{5}{e^x}$ $\rightarrow 0$ whan $x\rightarrow \infty$.